# I can not make a payment using a test sandbox account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

My web-based aplication receive paypal IPN, and I never had a problem with testing using the sandbox. Unfortunately, most recently at login to the test account to pay the test payment page becomes blank and nothing happens, or I can not choose the "pay with my paypal account" option. I was looking for answers and found to clean your cookies files but it did not help. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: There are issues with sandbox; https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus

Comment: Yeah u have right, paypal said the same thing thanks!